# How to select non-parent elements by class and id with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to select element by id and class with JQuery function. Problem is that elements are not parents. Smth like this:

```
<div class="image"></div>

<div id="contact"></div>
```

My code is working but this isn't a solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(window).scroll(function() {

    $('.featurette-image').each(function() {

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ) {
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'}, 700);
        }

    });

    $("#contactme").each(function() {

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ) {
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'}, 500);
        }
    });

});
```

});

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it's working why it's not the solution?

Comment: because I should rewrite the same code. I think it is not the best way :) I'm just curious if it is possible to do it in simple way.

Comment: if I recall correctly you can join selectors like this if that what you meant `$('.featurette-image, #contactme')`

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join jquery selectors using commas `,` like so:

```
$("#contactme, .featurette-image").each(...
```

This behavior is described in their documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this :

```
$("#contactme, .featurette-image").each(function() {
  var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
  var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

  if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ) {
     $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'}, 700);
  }
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    $('body div').each(function() {

       if ($(this).hasClass('featurette-image') || $(this).attr('id') == 'contact') {

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if( bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object ) {
            $(this).animate({'opacity':'1'}, 700);
        }
      }
    });



  });
});
```